# Angular Routing partial views in miniSPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I've flipped through tons of the posts, and can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong. I have a main Layout page for Bootstrap navigation. and am trying to create a Student miniSPA.

I have a Index.cshtml page nested in the Layout, and am trying to load my List.html partial view. It's loading up to the Index.cshtml just fine, but refuses to load the partial ng-view.  I feel like i'm just missing something simple, but can't figure it out.

I'm using a _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Students", "Index", "Students")</li>    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>        
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

my Index.cshtml

```
@{ViewBag.Title = "Index";}
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/app/StudentFactory.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/app/StudentCrudController.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body ng-app="StudentDashboardModule">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("StudentDashboardModule", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {        
    $routeProvider
        .when("/Student", { templateUrl: "/List", controller: 'StudentCrudController' });        
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

and finally, my StudentController:

```
public class StudentController : Controller
{
    // GET: Index
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public PartialViewResult List()
    {
        return PartialView("List");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're fairly confused about how MVC routing is done server-side compared to how AngularJS does it client-side. When you define a route in the $routeProvider, no call is actually made to the server (i.e. the /List route is a server-side MVC route). AngularJS routing is done purely client-side. This means that when routing is done, no call is actually made to the server. The template URL in your route should be pointing a HTML file (e.g. /views/list.html). If you want to bind data in your view, you should create an Angular controller which loads this data and binds it to your view.

Comment: @Mark I was using this guide : http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=1054.  I've also tried doing as you've mentioned, `.when("/student", { templateUrl: "/Views/Student/List.html", controller: 'StudentCrudController' });` to no avail.

Comment: Can you see '/Views/Student/List.html' in the browser? i.e. http://host-name/Views/Student/List.html'?

Comment: I believe the answer will work for this situation.  However, I question why you would even use angular routing at all in this scenario, and not just route directly to the view from MVC.

Comment: @Claies I realize i can route MVC partials - i'm doing this more as an exercise since I'd like to familiarize myself more with angular.

Comment: @Claies just as a followup question, if i use MVC partial views, how can i get the angular controllers to behave with the partials?

Comment: Never mind, just had ng-app in the wrong div. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I as far as I think you are missing one thing. I have created a sample JSFiddle demo visit this. According to me 
in the templateUrl, you need to provide complete path like-

```
/ControllerName/List
```

Here is the sample demo on JSFiddle-

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mtV62/85/)

Comment: That does now link to the partial, however the partial is loading as a whole page instead of within the ng-view div.... Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. I managed to get it working. I just did not properly include the partial in my MVC controller